# Hosting a PHP webpage in wireless LAN

Tags: php, xampp

I made an web application using PHP and mySQL and i used XAMPP. I am on a LAN having 6 computers connected via wireless connection. I want to host my web application from my pc so that other pc can use that application.

Can you help me what to configure how to configure in my pc so that using just a single URL other computers can use my web application.

Thanks

Comment: I also recommend to have a look in httpd.conf. It might only listen to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your IP Address is pinging or not from client pc. If ping is ping server IP then move to step two.

   command> ping #Server ip address
2. Go to your XAMPP control panel find config button in the row of xampp and click to httpd.conf file
3. Search line which look like

   ```
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
   ```
4. Restart all services from XAMPP control panel

For more batter information please follow below links

[Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

[Set up xampp server on office lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926396/set-up-xampp-server-on-office-lan)

Comment: It worked.. Thanks. First I changed the localhost to my server ip in the httpd.conf file , then i allowed the firewall as public.

Answer (score 0):

On other computers you can just type the local IP of the PC that hosts the website in the browser URL field.

Answer (score 0):

check the IP of the server and type in client computer browser the ip address of the server.
like http://192.168.0.1 xampp already accessible through lan